# Echoing two arrays to Angular?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm having some trouble with returning two arrays from an ajax request from and to angular via PHP, either works fine but not returning both which seems strange. Tried putting the two arrays in one array but that results in either empty responses or just responses of "Array".

This is from my PHP code:

```
    $outp["arrayinarray"] = "$array";
    $outp["arrayinarray2"] = "$result";
    print_r(json_encode($outp));
```

And my JS:

```
$scope.go = function(EmailAccountId) {
    $scope.id = EmailAccountId;
        $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'search_hand.php',
      data    : $scope.id,
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
     })
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.formData.selectedServices = {};
        console.log("response data " + response.data);
        $scope.searchForm = true; 
        $state.go(nextState($state.current.name));
        }, function(error) {
          console.log("ERROR!");
          console.log(error);
        }
    );
};
```

The background to this is a simple search and edit application. Upon registration a file can be selected from the server which is done with a simple glob-function for selecting the file. Since it's a multi-step form the PHP for building this select seems to happen after angular has initialized and as a result that is always set to "default".

So I'm trying to rewrite the code and make Angular do the repeating of these files based on the response from glob but since a database select is also in this search function it just seems to die.

Why can't I return two arrays without breaking the code?

My console simply says "object Object" if two are returned but will display each object correctly if just one of those are echoed/printed back.

Comment: Code `$outp["arrayinarray"] = "$array";` is typecast array to string. You get an `Array` string with a Notice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object Object is usually shown when a object.toString() is executed. So in your case you are getting the json object with two arrays and you are trying to access it in a wrong way.So try printing to console like `response.data.arrayinarray` .

Comment: Imagine that, things work when you do them right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse json after getting the response. Suppose you encoded like :

```
 $outp["data"] = $array;
 $outp["status"] = 1;
 print_r(json_encode($outp));
```

than you need to decode and access like this:

```
.then(function (response) {
        console.log("response data " + response.data);
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        console.log(obj.status)
        console.log(obj.data)
```